# Alsa Sound not loading

Tags: 12.10, sound, alsa

I recently read a post from one of the boffins to use the `killall` command in terminal. I have tried that on numerous occasions with mixed results. Sometimes it works. I run an old Acer Aspire 3201. Up until 12.04 the sound worked fine, but since the last 2 upgrades Alsa doesn't load on boot, nor does it load the start-up sound. when I run `killall pulseaudio ; rm ~/.pulse*`, then reboot sometimes it works, but mostly it doesn't. Second, the terminal comes up with message that says it can't remove pulse because it is a directory. The problems with sound are driving me nuts. How do I get it working again so that it loads on start-up? Or how do I roll back to 12.04 which was the last stable platform?

Comment: PulseAudio always uses ALSA, so your question does not make sense. What is your actual problem?

Comment: the problem is when I start up the computer there isn't any sound so when I use the command in terminal and reboot sometimes it works, when I hear the bongos at login I know I've got sound. but even then sometimes the sound just switches of during use. I can be listening to You Tube or Rythimbox  or and suddenly have no sound. Up until 12.04 I had no trouble with the sound card but since the last two updates to this current version there has been nothing but problems.